# Sharepoint Powershell Form Library - Compare Date, Change Value

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I don't have much knowledge of Sharepoint Powershell but I'm attempting to piece something together to automate the checking of expiry date fields inside an infopath form library vs today's date.

I wish to compare every date in the following column,

```
Construction_x0020_Card_x0020_Expiry
```

To today's date. If the value is less or is null than today's date (meaning expired licence or no licence) modify the text in the following field:

```
Construction_x0020_Card_x0020_Type
```

This is what I have so far;

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq      $null) {
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$webUrl = "https://####"
$listDisplayName = "HR Employee Record"
$ExpiryDate = @($Construction_x0020_Card_x0020_Expiry)
```

?? Not sure if this works,$Construction_x0020_Card_x0020_Expiry is an array?

```
$TodayDate = (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
$convertedExpiryDate = $ExpiryDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

?? Not sure if this works, $Construction_x0020_Card_x0020_Expiry is System.Object[] trying to convert to System.DateTime

```
foreach ($item in $convertedExpiryDate.items | where {$convertedExpiryDate -lt $TodayDate}) {

if ($convertedExpiryDate -eq $null) {
Write-Host @($Construction_x0020_Card_x0020_Type)["$null"]
} elseif ($convertedExpiryDate -lt $TodayDate) {
Write-Host @($Construction_x0020_Card_x0020_Type)["Expired"]
} elseif ($convertedExpiryDate -ge $TodayDate) {
Write-Host @($Construction_x0020_Card_x0020_Type)["Valid"]
}
```

}

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: Maybe this isnt possible? :(

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible in powershell?